# Elastic4s, mockito and verify with type erasure and implicits

Tags: scala, mockito, elastic4s

In previous versions of Elastic4s you could do something like

```
val argument1: ArgumentCapture[DeleteIndexDefinition] = ???
verify(client).execute(argument1.capture())
assert(argument1 == ???)

val argument2: ArgumentCapture[IndexDefinition] = ???
verify(client, times(2)).execute(argument2.capture())
assert(argument2 == ???)
```

after several executions in your test (i.e. one `DeleteIndexDefinition`, followed of two `IndexDefinition`). And each verify would be matched against its type.

However, Elastic4s now takes an implicit parameter in its `client.execute` method. The parameter is of type `Executable[T,R]`, which means you now need something like

```
val argument1: ArgumentCapture[DeleteIndexDefinition] = ???
verify(client).execute(argument1.capture())(any[Executable[DeleteIndexDefinition,R]])
assert(argument1 == ???)

val argument2: ArgumentCapture[IndexDefinition] = ???
verify(client, times(2)).execute(argument2.capture())(any[Executable[IndexDefinition,R]])
assert(argument2 == ???)
```

After doing that, I was getting an error. Mockito is considering both three `client.execute` in the first verify. Yes, even if the first parameter is of a different type.

That's because the implicit(the second parameter) has, after type erasure, the same type `Executable`.

So the asertions were failing. How to test in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach now taken in elastic4s to encapsulate the logic for executing each request type is one using [typeclasses](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). This is why the implicit now exists. It help modularize each request type, and avoids the God class anti-pattern that was starting to creep into the ElasticClient class.

Two things I can think of that might help you:

1. What you already posted up, using Mockito and passing in the implicit as another matcher. This is how you can mock a method using implicits in general.
2. Not use mockito, but spool up a local embedded node, and try it against real data. This is my preferred approach when I write elasticsearch code. The advantages are that you're testing real queries against the real server, so not only checking that they are invoked, but that they actually work. (Some people might consider this an integration test, but whatever I don't agree, it all runs inside a single self contained test with no outside deps).

The latest release of elastic4s even include a [testkit](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-testkit/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/testkit/ElasticSugar.scala) that makes it really easy to get the embedded node. You can look at almost any of the unit tests to give you an idea how to use it.

Comment: I see your point. I still try to separate both kind of tests, but your answer is more generic. However I'll keep it open for some time, in case there are other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create one verify with a generic type. It took me a while to realise that even if there is no common type, you always have AnyRef.

So, something like this works

```
val objs: ArgumentCaptor[AnyRef] = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[AnyRef])
verify(client, times(3)).execute(objs.capture())(any())
val values = objs.getAllValues
assert(values.get(0).isInstanceOf[DeleteIndexDefinition])
assert(values.get(1).isInstanceOf[IndexDefinition])
assert(values.get(2).isInstanceOf[IndexDefinition])
```

I've created both the question and the answer. But I'll consider other answers.